# how to Locate Android device without turning on any location identification options

Tags: android, geolocation

I know a way to locate Android devices without turning on any location identification options. This way i use cell-id. Are there other ways to locate Android device without turning on any location identification options on the likes using cell-id? Thanks!

Comment: The built-in capabilities allow for location tracking using either GPS, cell or wifi, but they all require permissions and access requests from the application.  You could probably do a wifi lookup another way by estimating based on IP and find a library to do that.  But, no that is how it is designed.

Comment: According to [this page](http://www.zdnet.com/article/how-google-and-everyone-else-gets-wi-fi-location-data/), Google also uses Android  devices to collect these data as follows: 
`Android Location Services periodically checks on your location using GPS, Cell-ID, and WiFi to locate your device. When it does this, your Android phone will send back publicly broadcast WiFi access points' Service set identifier (SSID) and Media Access Control (MAC) data.`
So how to use that service?

Comment: You mean to ask, that you want to use the statistics that Google is collecting from our phones when we agree to the terms when we first encounter this on our devices?

Comment: Yeah. I found the answer [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/geolocation/). Now I can solve problem my boss gave to me. Thanks for your interesting :)